# cant mass assign the protected attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

iam working in rails 3.while trying to creating a user i am getting

```
cant mass assign the protected attributes error
```

I included following gems in the gemfile

```
gem 'authlogic' 
gem 'gemcutter'
```

and run `bundle install` in rails console

then create a a user model and add the required authlogic columns to the migration.

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string    :login,               :null => false  
      t.string    :crypted_password,    :null => false  
      t.string    :password_salt,       :null => false  
      t.string    :persistence_token,   :null => false  
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

and did `rake db:migrate`
Included `authlogic` in the user model.

```
# /app/models/user.rb  
class User < ActiveRecord::Base  
  acts_as_authentic  
end
```

while trying to create a user in rails console      `User.create(name: "pria",password: "priya123", password_confirmation: "priya123")`

iam getting

```
cant mass assign the protected attributes :name, :password, :password_confirmation
```

How can i rectify this error!

Answer (score 1):

In your `User` model:

```
attr_accessible :name, :password, :password_confirmation
```

Comment: @chinchu Your migration for creating the User model doesn't have those fields. Is it really like that?

Answer (score 0):

You must add these attributes to the `attr_accessible` list in your model.

For important information about mass-assignment and its security implications: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#mass-assignment